# error when add target host linux 7.9 on OEM 13.5

Tags: oracle-enterprise-manager

when I manually add target host on OEM 13.5, it's false at "Agent Deployment":

```
Execution of command cd /u01/app/oracle/oemagent/ADATMP_2023-06-12_08-53-25-AM;/u01/app/oracle/oemagent/ADATMP_2023-06-12_08-53-25-AM/agentDeploy.sh -ignorePrereqs ORACLE_HOSTNAME=dbwr1-vip AGENT_BASE_DIR=/u01/app/oracle/oemagent OMS_HOST=ocm19c.localdomain EM_UPLOAD_PORT=4903 AGENT_INSTANCE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/oemagent/agent_inst b_doDiscovery=false START_AGENT=false b_forceInstCheck=true -force AGENT_PORT=3872 on host dbwr1-vip Failed Error Message:Not Available
```

```
Exit Code :1 Fix the cause of the error and retry the operation
Execution of command (cd /u01/app/oracle/oemagent/agent_13.5.0.0.0/cfgtoollogs && /u01/app/oracle/oemagent/agent_13.5.0.0.0/bin/zip -q -r /tmp/remoteArchivesdbwr1-vip2023-06-12_09-31-38-AM.zip * -x oui/**\* OPatch/**\* oracle_common/**\*) on host dbwr1-vip Failed Error Message:/bin/sh: /u01/app/oracle/oemagent/agent_13.5.0.0.0/bin/zip: No such file or directory 

Exit Code :127 Not Available
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqcS5.png)

when I check target host, no file or folder exist same the error.

how can I solve this issue?

Brgs,

cancel and add target host again but not success

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1.) Create an empty file, OraInst.loc, on the agent server and provide full permission to the directory.
Example: D:\inventory\oraInst.loc

2.) Perform agent installation again by providing the following entry under the Additional Parameter section:

-invPtrLoc

Example:
-invPtrLoc D:\inventory\oraInst.loc